# Changing all absolute URLs anywhere inside the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have an HTML with the regular tags that looks similar to:

```
<html>
   <head> ... </head>

   <body> 

        ...some html....

        <script>
           window.siteRoot = "https://example.com"
        </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Now inside this HTML, I want to replace all absolute URLs with `example.com` as the domain to `/`. How could I do this?

I know I could change the `href` of the anchor tag by getting them and then altering their href, but here I want to do go beyond the anchor tags and find and replace the absolute URL, which could be anywhere as found in `script` tag above. How could I do this?

Comment: can you do it offline?

Comment: @Mr. Want to do this on the browser when page is rendering or has rendered.

Comment: @Mr. How will the method be different if I want to do this offline?

Comment: if you can process the file offline, then you could leverage [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html element [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) will help here.

On this example, I added quickly some *inline javascript*, just for the demo: `onmouseover="console.log(this.src)"`, so we can check the url on mouse over.

But again, it's pure html. It will apply to all relative urls in the document. If you need to avoid it for a particular element, then pass in the full url (`<img src="https://otherdomain.com/..."`)

You will see the src url of the `img` becoming `https://example.com/img.jpg`

```html
<html>
   <head> 
     <base href="https://example.com">
   </head>
   <body> 
        ...some html....
        
        <img src="img.jpg" onmouseover="console.log(this.src)">
       
         <br>
        
        <img src="https://otherdomain.com/remote.png" onmouseover="console.log(this.src)">

   </body>
</html>
```

Note that it can leads to anomalies with scripts and more, it's often a bit hard to use when it's become complicated.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, you could loop the DOM, and search each element with indexOf() for that url, and then change it. Use getElementsByTagName() in a loop, or each one check for the url with indexOf(), and include an if statement - it indexOf() > -1, reassign the url to the new one.

Comment: How will this work for the example I gave in the question?

Comment: var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    all[i].//fill in what you're looking for -innerText,innerHTML,atributes,etc.
}

Comment: within the block add an if statement - if(all[i].innerText,etc.indexOf('whatever url you're looking for,') > -1){all[i].innerText = newUrl}